# Story of Mrit Sanjeevni Mantra and Sanjeevni Plant

Tags: ramayana

Can any one shed light on Mrit Sanjeevni Mantra and how it came in existence, is it any way related to sanjeevni plant that is in Ramayana.

Is the sanjeevni plant just medicine effect like "jadi booti" or has some magical effects which can cure almost anything or bring someone back to life, or it has only selected medical effect.

If it can bring back to life, is there a time limitation to be before the Sun Rise.

How did these went extinct, can mrit sanjeevni mantra be used to bring some one to Life back ?